# How do applications find mouse selected files?

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to create a pure python windows program that can add the full path and filename of a mouse selected file to a list. I want to do what git does but without having to git init first...

I envision adding an option to the right click menu that fires up the app and then finds the path to the right clicked file and adds the path to a list.

I'm struggling to find a stable module that interacts with the win gui and can return the path of a file the mouse clicks or has selected...any ideas?

Comment: You mean you want the path of the file when it is dragged and dropped into your python window?

Comment: Ideally I would be able to find the path after simply right clicking or selecting...but i assume the difference between selected and dropped into a python window would be trivial...

Comment: I'm not 100% confident, but I think you are approaching the problem from a wrong angle. As far a I know the contents of the right click menu in Windows explorer is controlled by the registry. You'll probably need to edit the registry with `regedit` or use a specialized program for configuring the right click menu (or customize the installer if your app has one).